# Windows 10 Sound Settings for one app only

Tags: windows-10, system-sounds, timer

I have all sound turned off in Windows 10.  I'd like to install a timer and have it actually ring aloud.  The app included in the W10 download doesn't ring.  How do I enable sound for just one program?  Or is there another free download timer to try?  (I used to have Cool Timer, which no longer works well.)